# How can I install Jitterbit Studio 9.3 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, jitterbit

Is there a way to install Jitterbit Studio on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Your question is not about programming, it is about Linux. I suggest to ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com, or on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone trying to install JtterbitStudio 9.3 on Ubuntu 18.04, I prepared a recipe and I though on shearing it here. I haven't got the time to test thoroughly but seems to work ok.

First you need java (In case you don't have it already):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer;
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default;
java -version;

    java version "1.8.0_171"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

NOTE: put these in your .profile or .bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle;
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre;
```

Once Java is installed you need to download Jitterbit Studio for Mac OS X:

```
wget https://download.jitterbit.com/9.3b4TWcqvuVw45UdxQ/JitterbitStudio-9.3.1.3.dmg
```

We are going to need dmg2img to convert the dmg package into a usable filesystem image in order to mount it.

```
sudo apt-get install dmg2img;
dmg2img JitterbitStudio-9.3.1.3.dmg JitterbitStudio-9.3.1.3.img;
sudo mount -o loop -t hfsplus JitterbitStudio-9.3.1.3.img /mnt;
cd /mtn;
```

copy the "Jitterbit Studio 9.3.app" directory to it's final destination (I used my home directory):

```
cp -rp 'Jitterbit Studio 9.3.app' $HOME;
cd $HOME;
cd 'Jitterbit Studio 9.3.app'/Contents/MacOS;
cp launch-studio launch-studio.mac;
```

Edit the startup shell script:

```
vi launch-studio;

12d11
<   osascript -e "tell app \"System Events\" to display dialog \"$msg\""
15c14
< APP=$(mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier=="com.jitterbit.studio93" | head -1)
---
> APP="$HOME/Jitterbit Studio 9.3.app"; export APP
49c48
<     err=$("$JRE" -client $STARTUP_ARGUMENTS -splash:"$JITTERBIT_CLIENT_HOME/splashscreen.png" -Xdock:icon="$APP/Contents/Resources/client_icon_256_mac.icns" -classpath "$libdir/*:$JITTERBIT_CLIENT_HOME/configuration/" com.jitterbit.integration.client.osx.Jitterbit)
---
>     err=$("$JRE" -client $STARTUP_ARGUMENTS -splash:"$JITTERBIT_CLIENT_HOME/splashscreen.png" -classpath "$libdir/*:$JITTERBIT_CLIENT_HOME/configuration/" com.jitterbit.integration.client.osx.Jitterbit)

chmod 755 launch-studio;
```

and run it:

```
./launch-studio;
```

Hope this helps some one.

Comment: I gave this a shot.  Looks like the launch-studio code is not 100%.  Should that be placed in exact?  Should it replace everything in the existing launch-studio?

Comment: is a diff output from the original telling only the differences between the two files. so basically means: 12d11 (delete line 12 from the original file). 15c14 (change line 15 from the original for > APP="$HOME/Jitterbit Studio 9.3.app"; export APP). 49c48 (change line 49 from original file to  err=$("$JRE" -client $STARTUP_ARGUMENTS -splash:"$JITTERBIT_CLIENT_HOME/splashscreen.png" -classpath "$libdir/*:$JITTERBIT_CLIENT_HOME/configuration/" com.jitterbit.integration.client.osx.Jitterbit)).

Comment: Ahh...  that makes sense.  I completely missed the obvious there... lol  I'll test that today.

Comment: Very nice.  Great job.  If you don't mind I'll add this to our documentation.

Comment: That ill be awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.  Linux is not supported for our (Jitterbit) desktop studio.  It will be supported for the cloud studio that is in the works, though (since that will be web based).

It does look like you created a workaround.